# Wait until element becomes not readonly

Tags: nightwatch.js

In html page `select` tag by default has attribute `readonly=true` but after some time app removes this attribute. I need to wait until `readonly` attribute is removed before starting test. How can I do that?

```
'Test'(client) {
client
  .url('my url')
  .waitForElementPresent('#some_element:', 5000)
  .(here I need to wait before element becomes not readonly)
  .(continue...)
  client.end()
```

},

Comment: you can manually trigger the event or make the element readonly and then continue with your test.

Comment: I don't need trigger event, element becomes not readonly after few seconds automatically (when options of the select are loaded from server), I am only need to wait until this is done

Comment: In test cases, you dont wait, rather make it and start running desired tests, that's my point.